# Hardware for .NET Micro Framework

Tags: .net, hardware, .net-micro-framework

I would like start with .NET Micro Framework as my hobby project.

What hardware devices would you recommend for that?

Is there something like list of all hardware with support .NET Micro Framework?

Comment: I remember the MS site having a bunch of this info, but it seems to have disappeared!  For some reason all of the links are broken!

Comment: @smoore: I know about that site, but I want user recommendation based on some kind experience with that hardware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check following overviews:

[Microsoft .NET Micro Framework Tools & Resources](http://informatix.miloush.net/microframework/Hardware.aspx)
[Production Modules Comparison Table](http://informatix.miloush.net/microframework/HardwareComparisonModules.aspx)

I personally like the Thaoe-II and ChipworX most, for old .NET MF version I was really happy with the Digi ConnectME.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy to use: http://www.tinyclr.com/hardware/1/fez-domino/#/list/2/

Comment: I got my hardware in Wed night and had a credible starter program working in hours Thursday - turning on/off LEDs, reading buttons and POTS and using their remote.

Comment: tincyclr have added more boards for greater options.  So far every hardware purchase I have made has been very easy to make work.

Answer (score 3):

[Netduino](http://netduino.com/) is an excellent hardware you can look into.

This provides a great introduction :- http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/A-Gentle-Introduction-to-Netduino

This provides a excellent application of Netduino :- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/314774/Home-Automation-with-Netduino-and-Kinect

Answer (score 3):

Netduino is the best cost effective embedded development kit to start with.

Based on my experience, I would recommend that the development kit has a microcontroller without a memory management unit (like Netduino which uses a AT91SAM7X512 microcontroller).

.NET micro framework was designed primarily for memory constrained embedded devices whose core processing unit does not support external memory (SDRAM, NAND flash, etc..).

Developing on Netduino is more fun because your memory space is constrained and you will end up pushing yourself to write good efficient code.

Cheers!

Subbu

Answer (score 2):

When I was working on the Dare to Dream Different contest last year I had a chance to use the **[Tahoe-II](http://devicesolutions.net/Products/TahoeII.aspx)** from *[Device Solutions.net](http://devicesolutions.net/)*... it worked pretty well.  There are several other listed on the **[Micro Framework site](http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/default.mspx)**.  Most of the issues I ran into were platform limitation and not directly in the hardware.

Don't forget it is an embedded platform.  And a simple SPI bus with several devices on it may have issues with data contention.

The **[get hardware](http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/hardware/default.mspx)** link on the Micro Framework site has a list of supported hardware and vendors.

Answer (score 0):

This weekend I recieved my Fez Mini from GHI Electronics just $99.00. It comes with several devices to test (LED, Button, POT, etc)

I highly recommend adding the Wii Remote control adatper for this kit. You can connect your numchuck to it and detect both button press, joystick, and accelarometer readings. Hugh money saver since you can use this amazing Wii peripheral from the beginning.

This is my favorite kits so far primarily because it comes with extensive source code and samples. They also have a very good PDF ebook that takes you from start to coding with this board and devices. For a starter kit you can't get something easier.

Just be sure to update your firmware, first thing you do. A YouTube video is available on this task. It will save you sometime and fustration to just get that out of the way before starting your first sample.

http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/139

Answer (score 0):

I think ARM Cortex-M, currently is best architecture for micro-controller hobby. Particularly its [STM32 micro-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32) implementation. Is extremely cheap and widely used.

There is a [project that provides support for STM32 in .NET micro framework](http://www.mountaineer.org/netmf-for-stm32/).

[Netduino](http://netduino.com/hardware/) package STM32 with I/O devices (USB, Ethernet, ...), thats make things much more interactive and interesting )